# When SQLAlchemy will commit the record to the database?

Tags: python, session, sqlalchemy

I use the SQLAlchemy in my work, the code is like this:

```
with session.begin(subtransactions=True):
    order = Order(**data)
    session.add(order)

session.close()
```

When the code was executed, there no any new record in MySQL. If I change the code to this:

```
with session.begin(subtransactions=True):
    order = Order(**data)
    session.add(order)

session.commit()
session.close()
```

A new record will be inserted.

I think the record is cached by SQLAlchemy, But why I close the session and the session will not flush all data into database?

And I want to know whether I should `session.commit()` explicitly even if I am using the `with` statement with `session.begin()`. Because I read the SQLAlchemy and find if I use the `with` statement it should commit all my data if no exception raise or rollback if some exception raise.

Comment: SQLAlchemy wisely "in the face of ambiguity, refuses the temptation to guess" (`import this` at a Python interactive interpreter and ponder the "Zen of Python"!-) -- how could it guess whether you meant to commit or to rollback?!  "Explicit is better than implicit" (again, a key koan in the Zen of Python): be explicit, reduce your future "oops"es and regrets!

Comment: @AlexMartelli But I just think the `with` statement with `session.begin()` is a syntactic sugar just like `try...except` and its implement is a `try...except` in fact. So I think it's weird.